# Customize flask route function according to url get and post params

Tags: python, api, flask

Trying to map the params of request.form or request.args in the function parameter itself.. the dict represented in the function param

Ideal Method:

```
@app.route('/api',methods=['GET'])
def first_api():
    param1= request.args.get('param1')
    param2= request.args.get('param2')
    param3= request.args.get('param3')
    return 'whatever operation I want to  do'
```

My target:

```
@app.get('/api')
def first_api(param1,param2,param3):
    return 'any operations i want to do with these params'
```

so that in ajax I can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {'param1':'hello','param2':'stack','param3':'overflow' }
,
})
.done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
})]
```

Similarly for post

```
@app.post('/api')
def second_api(param1,param2,param3):
    return 'any operation with these params i want to do'



$.ajax({
    url: '/api',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'param1':'hello','param2':'stack','param3':'overflow' }
,
})
.done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
})]
```

how can i write a decorator function like get and post
I want to mainly operate on flask using parameters, my app heavily depends on that..

Some what like a asp.net feature
How can I write these custom methods...

Comment: what are you trying to do? pass param through get request and retrieve it in backend?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but I think `@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])` is what you're after?

Comment: I am  trying to get/map all the params that are present request,form or request.params dict in the function parameter itself...

Comment: What about something like this `@app.route('/api/<param1>/<param2>/<param3>')`

Comment: that is not what i need I am trying to change the 

what i want is something that parses url params ...

/api/?param1=value1&param2=value2&param2=value2

I am trying to shift some  back-end  code from .NET to python and there are sometimes a lot of params  passed like 12-30 in some  calls which needs a lot of work if I write in this format...